# Flutter: Make [Stack] lay out its children like [Colum]

Tags: flutter, layout, stack, rebuild

Is it possible to have a [Stack] that lays out its children like a [Column]?

The issue: A [SizeTransition] inside a [Column] rebuilds it whenever the animation is fired. With a [Stack], everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you try wrapping the `SizeTransition` with `RepaintBoundary`?

Comment: Trank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not solve the issue.

Comment: If you really want to go with `Stack`, you can try `Align` and/or `Positioned` to align/position the children components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not seeing the code, I'll conjecture on a couple things:

1. if the size of the animation container, particularly height changes with the animation, the whole column will need to rebuild.  So set a fixed height for the container of your animation.
2. Then just put that animation in its own Stateful Widget.  It should rebuild independently within the column, not rebuilding the column.

I'm betting that the column rebuilds because height of animation container is changing.